# Most likely sum of two dices

Tags: java, dice

I have two dices where the user can chooses the amount of faces on. I want to write a code to output the most likely outcome. For example if the user chooses 2 6-sided dices, then the outcome should be 7. But if the user chooses one 3-sided and one 4-sided dice, the output should be 4 and 5. I have seen examples where you calculate how likely each different sum is in different loops, but I am wondering if there is an easier way to go since I only care about the MOST likely sum, and not all sums.

Any advice or help would be appreciated!

Edit. Since it has not been appreciated to print all different attempts that I have done since there has been complaints about unnecessary code to read, I will link you to different examples I have tried, but then deleted since they seemed to be unnecessarily long for my problem.  https://coderanch.com/t/517923/java/Dice-probability-program-nested-loops I realized that that example wasn't fitted since that required an amount of rolls that I will not determine. I then tried to simply try all different possible combinations by using a while loop but I got stuck in the middle and therefore chose not go with it.

Now I only have:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
int x,y;
x=scanner.nextInt();
y=scanner.nextInt();
if (x==y) {
int z = x+1; 
System.out.println(z)
} else {
int z= ((x+y)/2)+1;
System.out.println(z);
}
}
```

Problem: if there are two different numbers of faces, the variable z only prints out ONE of the sum that are equally as likely to occur.

Comment: The word `dice` is already the plural of `die`.  Just wanted to correct your grammar.

Comment: What code have you tried already?

Comment: Stricly speaking, just returning 5 is the simplest and correct answer for your problem. Do you want to compute the result for different numbers of sides and/or dice?

Comment: I want the user to be able to choose the number of sides on two dices, so I want to compute the most likely outcome since that will be different for each user input!

Comment: @a.e.m.n It's `numSides + 1`, so easy to compute.

Comment: Or (numSides1+numSides2)/2+1, if the numbers do not have to be equal. (it does not matter if you round up or down, both are equally likely)

Comment: If x and y are your _dice_ you cannot compute x+y as you can only add up numbers. The answer is (5+7)/2+1=7. Furthermore, 6 and 8 have the same likelihood as 7, but that was not part of your question.

Comment: @floxbr but if the user chooses one 3-sided and one 4-sided and I write (variable1 + variable2)/2 +1 the output is 4, but it should be 4 and 5 since both of them are equally as likely to be the outcome?

Comment: @a.e.m.n If you want your output to be "4 and 5", you should phrase your question differently. As it stands right now, both 4 or 5 are correct answers.

Comment: @floxbr You are right, I have edited my question now. So, quite simply, I want the output to be the most likely sum, whether or not that is one or several different sums that are equally likely

Comment: @a.e.m.n but you still haven't tol us what you tried. We're here to help, but not to do your homework.

Comment: @JBNizet Not telling you to do my homework, which it is not (school is over). But earlier when I have written my code, there has been far too many complaints about me actually written my code because that was too much text to read. But now I have written some of my attempts, not all.. since that would be too much to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a and b be the number of sides and assume a is less than (or equal to) b. Then all sums between a+1 and b+1 and have the same likelihood (of a/(a+b)) and that likelihood is also maximal. How you want to return this in your code is up to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, it's difficult when you are new and find an interesting problem that seems easy.. yet it's not if you are new. Thanks again!

Comment: a=3, b=6 all sums btw 4 and 7? Your saying may be right. I’m asking the question since I don’t understand.

Comment: Yes, 4 = 3+1 = 2+2 = 1+3, 5 = 4+1 = 3+2 = 2+3 up to 7 = 6+1 = 5+2 = 4+3 all have 3 possibilities and therefore occur with probability 3/21 = 1/7.

Comment: @snr Correction: probability 3/18 = 1/6.